# Find all natural solutions to $(x+y+z)=xyz - 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Find all natural solutions to $(x+y+z)=xyz - 2$

I was able to find these solutions:
$x=y=z=2\\
x=1, y=2, z=5\\
x=1, y=3, z=3$

It also seems that they can't all be equal to $1$ at the same time.

I was just setting one of the variables to a fixed value. However, I struggle find all solutions through a proof.

Could somebody please give a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $x \ge y \ge z$. Some people define that natural numbers include zero, but if one number is $0$, then the left side is $\ge 0$, and the right is $-2$, so $x \ge y \ge z \ge 1$.

$yz$ cannot be $1$ because $x+y+z = x+2, xyz-2 = x-2$. If $yz = 2$ then $x+y+z = x+3, xyz-2 = 2x-2,$ so $x = 5$, solution $(5,2,1)$. If $yz = 3$ then $x+y+z = x+4, xyz-2 = 3x-2, x = 3$, solution $(3,3,1)$.

The left hand side is $\le 3x$. $3x \ge xyz - 2$ means $2 \ge x \times (yz-3)$. If $yz = 4$ then $x \le 2$ which only happens if $x = y = z = 2$. If $yz \ge 5$ then $x \le 1$ which cannot happen because $x \ge y \ge z$. Therefore $(5,2,1), (3,3,1)$ and $(2,2,2)$ are the only solutions.

So in this case setting $yz$ to a constant value instead of one variable worked quite well.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)